# How to add password protection to a manually invoked GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github-actions

I'm working with a small organization who would like to password protect their Production deployment pipeline. We are on a free plan that does not have access to Approvals, otherwise we would use Approvals.

I tried adding the following code:

```
jobs:
  verify-password:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Verify password
        run: |
          set -e
          echo "Verifying password..."
          INPUT_PASSWORD_HASH=$(echo -n "${{ github.event.inputs.password }}" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}')
          if [[ "$INPUT_PASSWORD_HASH" == "[REDACTED]" ]]; then
            echo "Password verification successful."
          else
            echo "Password verification failed."
            exit 1
          fi
```

This works, but the password is displayed in plaintext in the logs during the step where we set `INPUT_PASSWORD_HASH`.

Is there a way to disable the output or mask the password? Any other ways to implement this?

Tried adding `::mask-output::`, tried setting it to an env variable, tried researching ways to disable output

Comment: If you set the password as a workflow secret in the repo settings and then used it for comparison, it would get masked in the logs.

Comment: @tmt Thanks for the suggestion. However, wouldn't anyone in the repo be able to invoke the pipeline as it is a shared secret? Or can I restrict secret access to certain users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jp command you can parse the JSON that contains the data from the form.

!!! Anyone who can edit the action can also have the JSON output in which the password is in plain text. (`cat $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH`)

**Password:** foobar (c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c8974e592c2fa383d4a3960714caef0c4f2)

```yaml
name: Passwod-Test
run-name:  Passwod-Test
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      password:
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  check_password:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Verify password
      run: |
        set -e
        echo "Verifying password..."
        INPUT_PASSWORD=$(jq -r '.inputs.password' $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH) >> $GITHUB_ENV
        INPUT_PASSWORD_HASH=$(echo -n "$INPUT_PASSWORD" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}')
        if [[ "$INPUT_PASSWORD_HASH" == "c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c8974e592c2fa383d4a3960714caef0c4f2" ]]; then
          echo "Password verification successful."
        else
          echo "Password verification failed."
          exit 1
        fi
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly.

Follow up question: What do you mean by `Anyone who can edit the action can also have the JSON output in which the password is in plain text. (cat $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH)`? Simply that they could edit the action file to add a command to output the password if re-ran? If so, we should be protected here, as we have merge protection that would prevent this addition without approval.

Comment: Yes, I mean the editing of the action file. But if you have merge protection then you have it under control.